# PHP - method for detect certains number

Tags: php, regex

I want to detect if a variable is 0,1,2,3 or 4. How to do this with `preg_match()`? What about performance between it and `if($var==0||$var==1||$var==2||$var==3||$var==4)`?

Comment: A straight comparison is faster preg_match. Use in_array like the answer below

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't reflect what you have asked for. Otherwise a simple comparison would have done the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (in_array($var, range(0,4), true)) {
 // good
}
```

The third parameter will do a strict comparison so `$var` must be an integer

Comment: If $var is a string or a boolean value it'll return true.

Comment: And if $var is a POST variable? It's works (without true) using ctype_digit().

Comment: Yes, but a POST variable is a string, and it doesn't work with true parameter.

Comment: Than you can remove the third parameter. I'm not sure what the issue is. Can you explain if this doesn't as you need it to?

Comment: If I remove the third parameter, if $_POST['test'] is "abcd" it's return true. With third parameter, even if even $_POST['test'] is 5, it's return false.

Comment: I see what you mean. You would just need to verify the value is numeric before testing its value like you are with `ctype_digit()`. Normally you could just cast it to an integer but since zero is a valid value that won't work here.

Answer (score 1):

this is how you will do it by `preg_match`.

```
 /^[0-4]$/

 if (preg_match('/^[0-4]$/', $var)) {
    echo $var . " is ok";
 } else {
    echo $var . " is NOT ok";
 }
```

<kbd>[**Online demo**](http://3v4l.org/tR8cs)</kbd>

Comment: `*` means match zero or more times. Which means `[0-4]*` would match empty string, `00`,`44444`, `01234` etc...

Answer (score 1):

Direct comparison is absolutely much faster than using `preg_match()`

```
if (is_int($var) && $var<=4 && $var>=0){
 //Access granted
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing a straight comparison is almost always always faster than regex. Even if it's not in this case (and any speed benefits would be negligible), I would still avoid it because regex tends to be less straightforward.